# PHP File Download Error

Tags: php, image, file, download

I have a website with an image gallery and a custom build lightbox.
I'm providing the visitors to download the current displayed image. The url param's are passed properly, but somehow the script will only work on the first image the visitor downloads. After that im getting the error

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Unable to access . ( path )

All files exists, permissions are set properly.

The code to download a file is:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET[ 'file' ] ) && basename( $_GET[ 'file' ] ) == $_GET[ 'file' ] ) {

  $file = $_GET[ 'file' ];
  $path = $_GET[ 'path' ];

  $fullpath = realpath( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ) . '/' . $path . '/' . $file;

  if( $fd = fopen ( $fullpath , 'r' ) ) {

    $fsize = filesize( $fullpath );

    $path_parts = pathinfo( $fullpath );

    $ext = strtolower( $path_parts[ 'extension' ] );

switch( $ext ) {

  case 'pdf':
    $ctype = 'application/pdf';
  break;

  case 'exe':
    $ctype = 'application/octet-stream';
  break;

  case 'zip':
    $ctype = 'application/zip';
  break;

  case 'doc':
    $ctype = 'application/msword';
  break;

  case 'gif':
    $ctype = 'image/gif';
  break;

  case 'png':
    $ctype = 'image/png';
  break;

  case 'jpeg':
    $ctype = 'image/jpg';
  break;

  case 'jpg':
    $ctype = 'image/jpg';
  break;

  default:
    $ctype = 'application/force-download';
}

header( 'Pragma: public' );

header( 'Expires: 0' );

header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );

header( 'Cache-Control: private' , false );

header( 'Content-type: ' . $ctype );

header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'' . $file . '\'' );

header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );

header( 'Content-length: ' . $fsize );

header( 'Cache-control: public' );

while( !feof( $fd ) ) {

  echo fread( $fd , 1024*8 );

  flush();

}

  }

  fclose ( $fd );

}
?>
```

If I try to open the file directly in the browser with the provided filename and path it shows the image correctly.

Comment: Check your file has neccessary permissions.

Comment: From what I see, you're currently implementing a backdoor allowing a user with quite minimal hacking skills to download basically any file in your webroot. You really have to sanitize the input before  using it to serve a file.

Comment: hmm. To be honest, I got this script from a third-party website. mainly because I was too lazy to write it myself. Do you maybe have some leads to a better ( more secure as well ) version of such script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your web server have access to that directory (in apache www-data)?

Comment: Yes it does. I got all access to the directories and their files.
I take it you are referring to the chmod permissions?

Comment: does `file_exists()` return `true`?

Comment: That is the strange thing here. The first image to be downloaded is downloaded. Then if you click another image I get the error.

Comment: could you post a test case in your post and exact error messages?

Comment: You can view an example here: http://www.dehobbelhoek.nl/media/fotos/2013/november2013

Just click an image to open up the lightbox, the download button is at the bottom.

The error seems to occur at line 10, which is 


   if( $fd = fopen ( $fullpath , 'r' ) ) {

Comment: the first photo runs `fx.process.file.php` and second runs `fx.download.file.php` can you confirm that the path that is returned by `$fullpath` is 100% correct the first image is downloaded as `'img-20131120140041.jpg'.jpeg`

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I didn't see that! That was the fix! =D Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: and the $fullpath is 100% correct. All images are downloaded succesfully now. Just wondering now how that extra ".jpeg" in your answer happened. I'm getting all images without that extra extension or quotes.

Comment: changed:
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'' . $file . '\'' );
to:
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $file );